# Prove subspace of $L(v)$

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: Question]

Since $T$ is invertible, thus $T$ is bijective, then if $Tv$=0 iff $v=0$, then $v$ is inside of the $T$, then for some constant number $c$, such that $cTv = 0$ belong to $T$ then $T$ is a subspace of $L(V)$

Is this proof right?

I am a little bit confused.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this prove? I am appreciated for you help

Comment: $0 \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ is not invertible.

Comment: why it's not invertible?

Comment: That's because $T0 = 0T = 0$ for any $T\in\mathcal L(V)$.

Comment: Since  is invertible, thus  is bijective, then if =0 iff =0, 0∈()  is not invertible then T is not a subspace?

Comment: Then prove like this?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Or you may not fully understand the definition of the subspace. Part a) asks you if  $ \{T\in L (V): T\; is\; invertible\}$ is a subspace. To be a subspace, 0 has to be in it. Obviously, 0 map is not injective unless $V=\{0\}$  and thus not in it. Only when $V=\{0\}$, $ \{T\in L (V): T\; is\; invertible\}$ is a subspace.